# Get the last day of the next 6 months prior to the current date

Tags: php, date

I have problem with my code that gets the last day of the next 6 months. My code  gets first the last day of the current month then using the date function + 6 months.

```
$lastday = date("Y-m-t");
$lastdayaftersixmonth = strtotime("$lastday +6 months");
```

But my problem is when it comes to months that do not have same number of days specifically in case of august and february. If the last day for august is 31, supposedly it must return february 28 (or 29 for leap year), but it returns March 2.

Answer (score 0):

$date = date('Y-m-t',strtotime('+6 month'));
echo $date;